# Integer Conversion in Floating Point Arithmetic

Tags: c++, c

I currently face the following dilemma:

```
1.0f * INT32_MAX != INT32_MAX
```

Evaluating `1.0f * INT32_MAX` actually gives me `INT32_MIN`

I'm not completely surprised by this, I know floating point to integer conversions aren't always exact.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

The code I'm writing is scaling an array of rational numbers: from `-1.0f <= x <= 1.0f` to `INT32_MIN <= x <= INT32_MAX`

Here's what the code looks like:

```
void convert(int32_t * dst, const float * src, size_t count){
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        dst[i] = src[i] * INT32_MAX;
    }
}
```

**Here's what I ended up with:**

```
void convert(int32_t * dst, const float * src, size_t count){
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
        double tmp = src[i];
        if (src[i] > 0.0f){
            tmp *= INT32_MAX;
        } else {
            tmp *= INT32_MIN;
            tmp *= -1.0;
        }
        dst[i] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dunno but try `1.0 * INT32_MAX`... maybe `float` is to small for holding your number, so try it with `double`. That would require changing your whole program to `double`, though.

Comment: You just can't, *float* can store up to 7 significant digits.  But *int* requires 10 digits.  The inevitable loss of precision causes errors.  You must use *double* instead, provides 15 sigdig.

Comment: @cad Even if that worked, the actual conversion isn't taking place with numerical literals, see the code snippet that I posted.

Comment: @HansPassant The code is for an audio library, int32 to single precision conversion is a must. Also, note the range of the floating point array.

Comment: So? `double` may also be capable of holding `x * INT32_MAX`.

Comment: If it is audio then the range does not have to be perfect.  Map to INT32MIN+2 .. INT32MAX-1 instead.

Comment: @HansPassant well if you're absolutely certain that's the best compromise, I guess I could settle for that.

Comment: How do you determine that `1.0f * INT_MAX` yields `INT_MIN`?

Comment: Can you guarantee that -1.0f <= x <= 1.0f always holds ? If yes, there must be good reasons for that. Can you tell ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler a `printf` debug. `int32_t tmp = 1.0f * INT_MAX; printf("%d\n", tmp);`

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, most audio libraries use that range for floating point conversion. The significand is used for temporary overhead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler See my answer. Given the most common formats, 1.0f * 0x7FFFFFFF is rounded to 0x80000000 in the intermediate result. Storing this in a 32 bit int will make the int end up as, ehm, 0x80000000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IEEE754, 2147483647 is not representable in a single precision float. A quick test shows that the result of `1.0f * INT32_MAX` is rounded to  `2147483648.0f`, which  can't be represented in an int.

In other words, it is actually the conversion to int that causes the problem, not the float calculation, which happens to be only 1 off!

Anyway, the solution is to use `double` for the intermediate calculation. 2147483647.0 is OK as a double precision number.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for `INT32_MIN` and `INT32_MAX` perfectly.